# How can I cache an IMAP socket resource?

Tags: php, symfony, imap

I have created a php web email client where I retrieve email via socket from various email providers, I have pretty much all the functionality found in any email client with the exception that my email client takes too long for various operations, before I had created it using the `php-imap` extension and I thought it took too long and then I rewrote my code base to use sockets and do all the parsing myself.
It is far better connecting via socket than using the `php-imap` extension; however, I still believe it takes too long when comparing it with a desktop client or gmail via the browser. The email client is part of an invoicing web app I have created and I would really like to keep it together, instead of having to use a third party service for email.

Is there a way to cache/write to disk a resource connection to a remote IMAP Server?
Could I then retrieve and re-utilize this connection to send commands and read its output? All without disconnecting/logging out from the first session?

I believe having to constantly login to the IMAP server is the bottleneck in my webapp, any pointers or ideas where I could gain speed?